# std::map using large amounts of memory

Tags: c++, std

I have an array of bins:

```
vector<vector<int> > bins
```

The program calculates a large amount of object of the type `Term` and a corresponding integer. Every bin corresponds with a `Term` object, and the ints need to end up in the bins. I am currently doing this:

```
map<Term, int> helperMap;
int binNumber=0;
while(/*some condition*/)
     {
     Term temp;
     int tempInt;
     //Do some calculation to find temp & tempInt

     if (helperMap.find(temp)==helperMap.end())
          {
          vector<int> newBin;
          newBin.push_back(tempInt);
          bins.push_back(newBin);
          helperMap[temp] = binNumber;
          binNumber++;
          }

      else 
          {
          bins[helperMap.find(temp)->second].push_back(tempInt);
          }
      }
```

The problem is that the map (which I don't need anymore further on) requires much more memory than the bin structure, and this is putting serious constraints on the program. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like an XY problem to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: In what way? I am sure the calculation of the 'Term' object is required.

Comment: Should we assume `Term` and `Object` are synonymous in this code?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake on my part. I edited it.

Comment: How dreadful is `Term`, btw (including its `operator <` comparator)?. It would seem to me a weak ordering of that object class is pointless if it is never used for anything besides temporary identity lookups. An ordered map may not be the ideal approach to this.

Comment: `Term` stores 2 `vector<int>` with the same size. Those sizes can differ between different instances of `Term` though. I made a custom `<`, but didn't mention it in the sample code. I don't think I understand what you mean with your second sentence. Are there alternatives to ordered map? I was under the impression that an unordered map requires even more storage.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps. Spin through your loop once, calculate how many bins you're going to need, and call `bins.resize(numberYouWillNeed)` - Then spin through again and all you need is `bins[x].push_back(tempInt);` - This will result in far fewer memory allocations too, probably making this faster. Depending on whether your calculations are expensive and whether you can only do them once.

However, I can't see `helperMap` being enormously bigger than `bins` - are you sure that is the problem?

Comment: The reason 'helperMap' is much bigger than 'bins' is that the 'Term' objects store data that's much more than an int. 

I will go and try this, but don't I end up with a map of the same size? It still has to store every different 'Term' in the map right?

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately the program is still eating up all my memory. I know for a fact that it's the map eating it, because I can run the loop without filling the bins, just to see the memory the map uses.